# Remove Everything between Round brackets in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove round brackets and anything between them. Which RE i used ? I used below code but some some language like Hindi it's not work some time. Please any one help me.

```
nl2br(preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$main_ary[$y]." "));
//Ex. एंड्रॉयड 4.4.2 (किटकैट) ऑपरेटिंग सिस्टम पर
//I want एंड्रॉयड 4.4.2 ऑपरेटिंग सिस्टम पर
```

Comment: works here http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/61

Comment: You need to use the "u" modifier to indicate that the string must be read as utf-8: `/\([^)]+\)/u`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lazy selection (`.*?`) to skip all sorts of characters until the first occurrence of the next character in the regular expression (`)`) is reached.

```
preg_replace("/\(.*?\)/","",$main_ary[$y]." ")
```